# NSUTF8StringEncoding result encoded string with 'Optional' string

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using `NSUTF8StringEncoding` to encode some text inputs, the inputs get encoded and the resulting string contain a 'Optional'. An example worked out is available [here](http://swiftstub.com/70868863/).

What does that encoded string with 'optional' really mean?

Does that have any significant role?

Comment: "Optionals" are a key concept of the Swift programming language and explained in detail in the official Swift book ...

Comment: If you read the documentation of the function you are calling, you will find that there is no guarantee that the conversion will succeed, so you might not get a result. That's why the result is optional; it lets you check whether you suceeded or not.

Comment: It means you should use  "if let data = ... { ... }

Comment: @gnasher729 ,thank you ..but here in this case output was available then too optional gets printed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you have to understand is that an optional is a different data type than the required object it contains. An optional "wraps" or contains some other object. The optional can either be empty, represented by nil, or it can contain another object.

Internally an optional is an enum that has 2 values, Some and None. The Some case has an associated value. Optionals are generics. The associated value stored in the Some case (non empty) can be any type, and that determines the type of the optional.

If you print an optional, you see the container AND the value stored inside, or you see nil (since a nil optional does not contain anything.)

```
let aString:String? = "Foo"

println("aString = \(aString)")
```

Displays something like

> optional("Foo")

That's because aString is not a String optional, it is an optional that **contains** a string.

Comment: thank you @Duncan,it made me confused eventhough answer was printed it was appended with 'Optional'

Answer (score 1):

optional variables are variables that can may or may not have a value.
Looking at your example [here](http://swiftstub.com/70868863/)

we can see data has type NSData?

unlike objective-c where we can happily send messages to nil values we need to make sure the 'data' definitely has a value before we can use it

if you are sure it will have a value you can unwrap it explicitly like this

```
let myString = "encode me"
let data : NSData? = myString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

data!.someNSDataFunction()
```

This will crash if data is nil.To safely unwrap it  you can can do this

```
if let actualData = data
{
    actualData.someNSDataFunction()
}
else
{
    println("data has not been set")
}
```

Comment: but that example produced a value ..then how come it become optional?..correct me if im wrong

Comment: The definition of the method is: `func dataUsingEncoding(_ encoding: UInt) -> NSData?`. The ending `?` indicates that an `Optional` is returned.

Comment: the function defines the return value as optional. So the type will be optional if it has a value or not.  func dataUsingEncoding(_ encoding: UInt) -> NSData?

Comment: NSUTF8StringEncoding is a type def NSUInteger so it could be valid  as far as the compiler is concerned to  call the function with some random number as the encoding variable. This means the return value could be nil or a valid data object